# Jquery flip color still gray?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, flip

im using this flip plugin from http://lab.smashup.it/flip/
It works great and I can change color in flip animation but not completely. I can only change 50% of the color in the flip function. As you can see on their website when you flip you see a bit of "gray". I would really like to change this to another color. Is it possible? has anyone else done this?

Please note: I know that this changes the color but it doesn't completly change it and the gray still exists in 50% of the flip

```
$("#flipbox").flip({
direction:'tb',
color:red,
content:'this is my new content'
})
```

Comment: Yes, sorry i forgot to add "red". But originally its added and still the gray at 50% of animation

Comment: Seems to work in my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/styson/av93g/).

Comment: I tried your jsfiddle and It sure does work but I figured just now that im using the latest UI 1.8.18. try to check that option then try the fiddle you will then see the gray

Answer (score 1):

Using jQueryUI does seem to make the difference. I've had the same problem, so I forked jquery.flip and made it use the previous background color and the new background color as transition colors:

> https://github.com/Data-ptr/Flip-jQuery

I have a pull request in to roncioso right now.